# can't get GETCHLD signal for second time c linux eclipse

Tags: c, linux, signals, kill, sigaction

i have program which sends signal SIGCHLD to all other processes in the system TWICE. problem is, its sent only once.

program sending the signal:

```
 int main(){
 kill(-1, SIGCHLD);   
 sleep(8);
 kill(-1, SIGCHLD);
 return 0;}
```

program getting the signals:

```
int main(){
struct sigaction sigchldHandler;
sigchldHandler.sa_flags = 0;
sigset_t BlockMask;
sigfillset(&BlockMask);
sigchldHandler.sa_mask = BlockMask;
sigchldHandler.sa_handler = sigchldFunction;
if( sigaction( SIGCHLD, &sigchldHandler, NULL ) != 0 ){
      perror( "sigaction() error\n" );}
    while(1){
       pause()}
return 0;
}
```

the function is:

```
void sigchldFunction(int signal){
write(1, "gets here only once\n", strlen("gets here only once\n"));
startHandling();
}
```

why doesn't it get the second signal, byt only the first one?
...HELP??

Comment: First I suggest you to learn how to format your code properly. Readability of the code is half of it's success.

Comment: its as short and clear as possible..

Comment: `short != clear`. Don't save on spaces and newlines. Haven't you seen the other questions with code around here?

Comment: u r right.. net time ill try. anyways, do you see anything here?

Comment: You don't show us the code for `startHandling()` so we can't be sure, but you are presumably inside `startHandling()` with SIGCHLD _blocked_ from your signal handler because [you didn't specify SA_NODEFER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36069374/132382).  Thus the second signal is effectively ignored until you leave the signal handler.

Comment: so if I add the blocks, it should work ? like I editted?

Comment: With signal handlers, you do as little as possible in the signal handler before returning — call as few functions as possible, do as little work as possible, get back as soon as possible.  Your process will receive no signals at all until it returns from `sigchldFunction()`.  That's what blocking all the signals means.